# Which one should I use?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I am building this website application using Laravel 6 and React Native for the mobile app. The question is:

Should I use

```
return response()->json($products);
```

or `return $products->toJson();`

Which one should I use to fetch the data from my Laravel 6 back end application to the React Native app?

Comment: I don't know that it really matters. Both should return the same information, but the first may have additional header information.

Comment: I am not sure what does the "Header" is used for? I am new to this json fetching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the methods are correct. Laravel will automatically convert anything you pass as return of a controller method to a `Illuminate\Http\Response` object, so you can return:

- Booleans
- Strings (including JSON strings)
- Arrays
- Responses
- JsonResponses

When you use `response()` it allows you setting response code and headers. Returning directly the json you won't be able to do that.